# Ender 3 V2 Z-axis base value changes for each print

Tags: creality-ender-3, bed-leveling, z-axis

I'm new to 3D printing, I just bought an Ender 3 V2 and I am having a lot of trouble with bed adhesion. After a lot of playing around it seems that the base value for Z is changing for every print.

I have been using [this Z-offset test](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:3771049) model, dialing in my Z-offset during the print until I hit an acceptable value (eg. -0.15)

If I then print the same model again, using the value I found above, it is way off again, and I have to dial it further down to maybe -0.40 and, if I repeat again, to 80.

I have, of course, tried leveling my bed multiple times

I've just been scribbling down numbers and seeing them fail for two days now, so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Hi Viggo! Are you using a BLTouch (or similar) sensor? If so, are you saving your Z-offset adjustment to the EEPROM?

Comment: @Rykara I don't have a BLTouch, but I am considering buying one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tightening the screws on the X-axis gantry and doing the bed leveling and test prints again it seems to have gotten better.

Also, while I was under the impression that the V2's heated glass bed *should* work well without adhesive, I applied a bit of glue stick and now my first print seems to have a perfect first layer.

I may just have been confused because I needed to turn the Z-offset way down to get it to stick in the first place, and then tweaked it upwards to get nice lines, meaning I would have to dial it back down on next test print and so forth.

Comment: I found the bed levelling knobs on the Ender 3 v2 are prone to be easily nudged and vibrated out of position over time requiring regular relevelling. I use gluestick for every print even with a heated glass bed